# Get index number of image tag in array

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array and I'm trying to write a function using javascript to return the index of the image tag in the array. Where `img` and `p` are tags in my code all are sharing the same class.

```
const getClass = document.querySelectorAll('.grp1')
const intoArray = Array.from(getClass)
console.log(intoArray) ====>  [img.headPic.grp1,p.grp1,p.grp1]
```

I've tried using `indexOf('img')` but it returns `-1`, meaning it couldn't find it in array.

Comment: you array item is 'img.headPic.grp1' not img.
Try  indexOf('img.headPic.grp1').

Comment: You are passing a string to indexOf, but you want to pass the variable `img`. Use `indexOf(img)` instead

Comment: indexOf('img.headPic.grp1') will only work for that specific value and type. Please clarify whether the value changes arbitrarily and whether the type is always a string or is it an object or what?

Comment: This question needs more code that sorta works. Hard to tell what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @VahanNasibyan: Why would looking for the string `'img.headPic.grp1'` be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array and inspect each element's node name. E.g.

```
var index = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < intoArray.length; i++) {
  if (intoArray[i].nodeName === 'IMG') {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

There are all sorts of ways of iterating over an array and getting the data you want. If [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is available, then use that instead:

```
var index = intoArray.findIndex(function(element) { return element.nodeName === 'IMG'; });
```

---

You could also directly query for the element and use `indexOf`:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img.grp1');
var index = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.grp1')).indexOf(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently looking for a string and not for an instance. `.indexOf('img')` can't work since you're looking for the string `"img"`and not for an actual image element. You need to query it first through something like `document.querySelector('.headPic')`

If you posess the image instance, you can indeed search for the instance through the array with indexOf. **Only if the array is actually an array!**

Most of the document querying functions (document.getElementsByName, document.querySelectorAll, etc.) return what is known as a NodeList. Most of the array-like functionalities are implemented on that kind of objects (such as loops), but not all of them. To be able to use indexOf (filter, forEach, map), you must make sure that the object is converted to an Array first.

David Walsh details how to to so [here](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array).

> ```
> var nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"))
> ```
>
> The result of the code above is a true Array object containing all of the nodes returned by the QSA.  You could even make the code shorter with this alternative:
>
> ```
> var nodesArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));
> ```

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.grp1');
var img = document.querySelector('.headPic');
// el.indexOf(img);
// this can't work right now because the object is still a NodeList at that point
var el_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(el);
var num = document.querySelector('.numIndex');

num.innerHTML = el_array.indexOf(img);
```

```html
<p class="grp1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus animi.</p>
<p class="grp1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus animi.</p>
<img class="headPic grp1" src="http://placehold.it/200/300">
<p class="grp1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus animi.</p>
<p>Index of the image is <span class="numIndex"></span></p>
```

Comment: The OP is already converting the list to an array. See their latest update.